# How to detect php -oracle using ubuntu nginx php7-fpm

Tags: nginx, oracle, php7

I am running a Ubuntu-nginx-php7-fpm machine and phpinfo() does not detect the oracle extension.

How can i tell to nginx or php that the oracle-php extension is installed?

The machine is a clone from another where oracle php7-fpm works.

When running phpinfo() from php oracle is not listed and even oci-connect does dot works or is listed at the error.log

Comment: If `phpinfo` doesn't show the extension it's *not* installed.

Comment: yes i know ! i meant much more about how to discover where instantclient oracle is installed, and how to make php7-fpm to detect oracle or install php7-oracle extension

Comment: To my knowledge, PHP 7 isn't available in Ubuntu's repositories yet, so you'll have to ask whoever provided your packages.

Comment: Oracle is not on /etc/php/mods-available  only : json.ini  mysqli.ini  opcache.ini  pdo_mysql.ini wich action can install oracle module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot provide what is missing in your case.
Here are all the steps to enable oci 8 for php-fpm.

**First install oci8.so using steps bellow:**

Install PECL, PHP Development files, Build Essential, Unzip, and the AIO Library

```
apt-get install php-pear php7.0-dev build-essential unzip libaio1
```

Create the oracle directory

```
mkdir /opt/oracle
```

Download instant client from this [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html?ssSourceSiteId=ocomen). Download 11.2 Basic & SDK. Only 11.2 version was working for me.

Move the downloaded files

```
mv instantclient-* /opt/oracle
```

Unzip the files using the unzip command (unzip )
Rename the created directory

```
mv instantclient_11_2 instantclient
```

cd into the instant client directory and create the following soft links

```
ln -s libclntsh.so.11.2 libclntsh.so
ln -s libocci.so.11.2 libocci.so

cd to  /opt
```

set the permissions on the directory

```
chown -R root:www-data /opt/oracle
```

Add the instant client to the the ld config files

```
echo /opt/oracle/instantclient > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient
```

Update the Dynamic Linker Run-Time Bindings

```
ldconfig
```

Install OCI8 using PECL

```
pecl install oci8
```

When you are pompted for the client location enter the following:

```
instantclient,/opt/oracle/instantclient
```

**Lastly configure php.ini**

At this moment your oci8.so is ready to be use. Just include into your php.ini file.

```
cd /etc/php/mods-available/
vi oci.ini
```

then add this line to the file "extension=oci8.so"

Now create a symlink like this:

```
cd /etc/php/7.0/fpm/config.d/
ln -s /etc/php/mods-available/oci.ini 20-oci.ini
```

Add oracle enviroment variables:

```
vi /etc/environment
```

Add the following lines:

```
# Oracle Instant Client
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/oracle/instantclient"
export TNS_ADMIN="/opt/oracle/instantclient"
export ORACLE_BASE="/opt/oracle/instantclient"
export ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE
```

Finally restart fpm service:

```
sudo php7.0-fpm restart
```

You must be able to check oci8 extension through phpinfo.

Comment: Thank you for your response this is the best answer about php7 , now is up and running